# Can someone explain how the JavaScript code works so that I can get a better understanding of how callback and requestAnimFrame are working?

Tags: javascript

I am new to the JavaScript canvas and game programming. In this bit of code below that I borrowed from someone else is the window the object and is the requestAnimFrame and user defined name. There is function that looks to be described as a anonymous name frame. And is the function callback in both the functions repaint the screen back to the window. theer are several ORs which I am not certain do what.

If someone could explain this I would help in the long run.

```
 window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback){
        return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||

        function(callback){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };

    })();
```

Comment: It seems to originate from here: http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is just a slick way of assigning a vendor specific `requestAnimationFrame` function to `window.requestAnimFrame`, or if none of those window members exist, an anonymous function that takes a callback and executes it every `1000 / 60` ms.

Comment: I see, if there are no animation frames then one is created that is called every 60 ms per second. Neat

Answer (score 0):

Using `value = something || something_else` is a shortcut to assigning a value where you're unsure if one of those values is undefined. The first one will get the value.

Answer (score 0):

- For better understatndig of requestAnimationFrame : [mozilla's artilce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame)
- different browsers have different names for the same function, some don't even support it, hense hte OR's : they are there so that application can work in different browsers.